# How to set app name from Java code in Android? Or How to set string.xml value from sqlite or anywhere else?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some value in string.xml, But I took app name value from server using json and wants to be a app name. Or set to a string.xml.

Comment: You can’t do that easily, plus it does not really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for SharedPreference or database storage for taken values of string which u want to give it for app name. Not sure about this but try once.

Comment: Yes, But after storing value in shared preference, How I apply to app as app name ? Any Idea?

Comment: @RahulSanap Dont Know, If you got any idea then please mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

The Class com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient has a function

```
public Builder setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
      this.applicationName = applicationName;
      return this;
    }
```

When using Gradle to generate your client libraries using appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs You should be able to create an endpointbuilder for your endpoints:

```
private YourEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new YourEndpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                }
            }
    );
```

then... to get rid of the warning:

endpointBuilder.setApplicationName("Application Name");

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to display on the home screens, then I don't think there is really any way to do this as it reads out of the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Saying that, if you have a defined set of values, then consider using the Gradle file to create the string depending on which flavor/build type you're using.

This can be done fairly simply with:

```
resValue "string", "app_name", VARIABLE_NAME
```

Put the values in gradle.properties, these are one line per value, e.g.

```
VARIABLE_NAME="My App Name"
```

Using productFlavors and buildTypes will give you more control, but not allow you to change the values from a server based file.

I hope this helps.